# Use wishlist as backorder

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, backorder

I have a specific requirement where I want to allow backorders, if the product is "out of stock" but I don't want the product to be added on cart or process for checkout but just store the product backorder for the customer and notify him/her through email with the link of the product when its back on stock.

The wishlist is doing same and so I copied it to local > Mage > Wishlist and observe the `withlist_add_product` to add the product to `product_alert_stock`. It's working fine except the link contains wishlist in the url and messages. I believe, I can change the messages but I'm not sure how can I change the url part.

Can someone guide me to change the url linking of the Wishlist? Would it better to keep it as Mage > Wishlist or shall I create the module and rename something like Backorders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either try creating a custom module with the appropriate frontname and then extend the with list controller and update the post url.

or

try to using  a rewrite in your config.xml

```
<global>
  <rewrite>
    <fancy_url>
         <from><![CDATA[/customModule\/(.*)/]]></from>
         <to><![CDATA[customModule/controller/view/name/$1/]]></to>
         <complete>1</complete>
     </fancy_url>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474491/magento-shorten-the-url-of-a-module-rewrite-with-htaccess

Comment: Thank @R.S, your solutions works. Sorry for late reply.